# Drawing a circle around nodes in flow chart using Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes

I am trying to draw a circle around a bunch of nodes in a flow chart that I've created using `beamer` and I can't figure out how to do it.  Ideally, I'd like the circle to encompass most (but not all of the nodes).  How do I do this?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The Regime Complex for Climate Change\\(Keohane and Victor (2011) )}


\tikzstyle{type1} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=0.1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!10, text width=2cm]

\tikzstyle{type2} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=0.1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!10, text width=5cm]

\tikzstyle{info} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=0.1cm, text centered, draw=black, 
fill=blue!30, text width=2.5cm]
\tikzstyle{org} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=0.1cm, text centered, draw=black, 
fill=blue!30, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [square, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.1cm, text centered, 
draw=black, fill=green!30, text width=4cm]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.2cm]

\node (un) [type1, xshift=-3cm] {UN Legal Regimes};
\node (expert) [type1, right of=un, xshift=4cm]{Expert Assessments};

\node (montreal)[type1, below of=un, xshift=-1cm]{Montreal Protocol};
\node (bilateral)[type1, right of=montreal, xshift=3cm]{Bilateral Initiatives};
\node (clubs)[type1, right of=bilateral, xshift=2cm]{Clubs};

\node(subnat)[type1, below of=montreal, xshift=1cm]{Subnational Action};
\node(MDA)[type1, right of=subnat, xshift=4cm]{MDA};

\node(geo)[type1, below of=subnat, xshift=-1cm]{Geoengineering Governance};
\node(nuc)[type1, right of=geo, xshift=2cm]{Nuclear Technology};
\node(fin)[type1, right of=nuc, xshift=2cm]{Financial Market Rules};

\node(intel)[type2, below of=geo, xshift=1cm]{Intel Property and Investment Rules};
\node(trade)[type2, right of=intel, xshift=5cm]{International Trade Regime};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. If you select your code and click on the button marked `{}` it will be highlighted as you see above. (Edit: I also added a missing semicolon after the last node.)

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved using the `fit` library, using for example

```
    \node[draw=red,double,fit=(un) (montreal) ,inner sep=1ex,circle] (tmp) {};
```

[image: screenshot]

Note that in the code below I have used `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle` as described in [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{type1/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=0.1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!10, text width=2cm},
        type2/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=0.1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!10, text width=5cm},
        info/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=0.1cm, text centered, draw=black, 
            fill=blue!30, text width=2.5cm},
        org/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=0.1cm, text centered, draw=black, 
            fill=blue!30, text width=3cm},
        decision/.style = {square, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.1cm, text centered, 
            draw=black, fill=green!30, text width=4cm},
        arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth},
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{The Regime Complex for Climate Change\\(Keohane and Victor (2011) )}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.2cm]

        \node (un) [type1, xshift=-3cm] {UN Legal Regimes};
        \node (expert) [type1, right of=un, xshift=4cm]{Expert Assessments};

        \node (montreal)[type1, below of=un, xshift=-1cm]{Montreal Protocol};
        \node (bilateral)[type1, right of=montreal, xshift=3cm]{Bilateral Initiatives};
        \node (clubs)[type1, right of=bilateral, xshift=2cm]{Clubs};

        \node(subnat)[type1, below of=montreal, xshift=1cm]{Subnational Action};
        \node(MDA)[type1, right of=subnat, xshift=4cm]{MDA};

        \node(geo)[type1, below of=subnat, xshift=-1cm]{Geoengineering Governance};
        \node(nuc)[type1, right of=geo, xshift=2cm]{Nuclear Technology};
        \node(fin)[type1, right of=nuc, xshift=2cm]{Financial Market Rules};

        \node(intel)[type2, below of=geo, xshift=1cm]{Intel Property and Investment Rules};
        \node(trade)[type2, right of=intel, xshift=5cm]{International Trade Regime};

        \node[draw=red,double,fit=(un) (montreal) ,inner sep=1ex,circle] (tmp) {};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean "`tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle`" right? `:)`

Comment: Isn't the `of=` syntax deprecated or something, in favour of `=of` with the `positioning` library? There was a question about this, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Found it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz

Comment: @KevinC thanks- got the code right, but not the description :)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes indeed, thanks for the link... it requires a fair bit of tweaking to update it- I'll leave that as something for the OP